# GWT Error ! No source code is available for type org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, xml, gwt, rpc

I got this compilation error during my GWT Compilation. I am using this to parse an XML document.

```
[ERROR] Line 24: No source code is available for type org.w3c.dom.Node; did you forget to     inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type org.w3c.dom.NodeList; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

From whatever research i did regarding this it says the classpath might be missing, but since this will be included by default in gwt-user.jar and JRE7, and i have not included any external jars also, so no case of duplicates ! And you cannot have these type of codes in Client side code since it will be converted to javascript

I have a class which makes use of this Node in my shared folder (GWT Model View Presenter Project structure ), which is basically a model !

1. Is moving the code to server side is the only possible solution?
2. If 1 is true,  how would i be able to refactor my client side presenters accessing this model without the over head of RPC call everytime ?
3. Are there any alternate approaches to this ?

---

My GWT config file.

```
 <module rename-to='xxxxx'>
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>


 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> 
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML" />

  <entry-point class='com.xxxx.xxxxx.gwt.client.ProjectEntry'/>


  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

 </module>
```

Edit : I have included the xml inherits now ! Its working

Comment: could you post your GWT module config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

somewhere in your code base you are using org.w3c.dom.Node and org.w3c.dom.NodeList these are not white listed. In other words you can not use these classes! see;

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation

you should use these packages for xml;

```
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Node;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList;
import com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but now it says- 
      [ERROR] Line 25: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.xml.client.Node; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [ERROR] Line 29: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.xml.client.NodeList; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: problem solved by adding gwt.xml modul 
<inherits name ="com.google.gwt.xml.XML"/>

Comment: Nice :) figured it out ! But now i have some problems regarding java.util collections !